# Телеграмм Бот не может разбанить юзера

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Функция для отправки сообщения:

```
const TOKEN = '99999999:AAAAAAAJjZ_T6hAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
const URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.TOKEN.'/';

function sendGetRequest($method,$params=null){
    if($params){
        $url = URL.$method.'?'.http_build_query($params);
    }else{
        $url = URL.$method;
    }
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
}
```

Вызов функции:

```
$un_ban_params = [
    'chat_id'=> $chat_id,
    'user_id'=> $user_id*1,
        ];

sendGetRequest( 'unbanChatMember', $un_ban_params);
```

Вызов возвращает null
Соответственно link на возвращение в группу не появляется

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден. "unbanChatMember" действует только в супергруппах и каналах. Для простой группы этот метод не действует.